# Android Sqlite - update multiple rows with multiple values

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to update multiple rows in sqlite where each row gets a different value.

Currently I'm just looping on the update statements. (I'm using SQLStatement and replacing the parameters).

I know that with MySql there is an option to use the CASE command to execute one update that will update all rows with the matching values.

Is there any similar thing in sqlite?

Thanks.

Comment: add your update code here.......

Answer (score 0):

If you know how your query should look like you can use either `query()` or `rawQuery()` methods instead of update

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I've concatenated the update queries, separating them with semi-colons and used rawQuery. The code runs but the table isn't updated.